# Is $Q_p^q(\lambda) = (\delta_{ij} + \lambda\delta_{ip}\delta_{jq})$

Tags: matrices, kronecker-symbol

Is this correct: $Q_p^q(\lambda) = (\delta_{ij} + \lambda\delta_{ip}\delta_{jq})$

With $Q_i^j(\lambda)$ is the unit matrix with $\lambda$ at the i-th row and j-th column (author calls it type II unit matrix, but shouldn't matter).

Am I wrong or is $\delta_{ip}\delta_{jq}$ just $n$ at $p=q$ and $0$ otherwise and therefore $Q_p^q(\lambda) \neq (\delta_{ij} + \lambda\delta_{ip}\delta_{jq})$ because the right side is $\lambda n$ at p-th row, q-th column and $1$ diagonally? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right, your matrix matrix $Q_p^q(\lambda)$ is the identity matrix plus the term $\lambda$ at position $p,q$. For example for dimension $n=4$

$$
Q_2^3(\lambda) = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & \lambda  & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

PS

Note that to be precise you should write $[Q_p^q(\lambda)]_{i,j} = \delta_{i,j} + \lambda \delta_{i,p} \delta_{j,q}$, as these are the components of the matrix.

Comment: Which is not $\delta_{ij} + \lambda\delta_{ip}\delta_{jq}$, which has $n\lambda$ where $Q$ has $\lambda$, correct?

Comment: Ehm no. That's exactly what I wrote and there is no $n$. I just meant you should define your matrix by giving the components ($i,j$ in your example). whereas $p$ and $q$ are parameters of your matrix $Q$. For each $p,q$ you have and $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: $\delta_{i,p} \delta_{j,q}$ is always zero, except when $i=p$ *and* $j=q$, in which case it's one.

Comment: Hmm... why's that? Isn't $\delta_{i,p}$ all ones in row p and $\delta_{j,q}$ all ones in column q? http://goo.gl/NdoaX0

Comment: By definition $\delta_{i,p}$ equals one if $i=p$ and it's zero otherwise. Try to play with the following: L = 4; Q[p_, q_] := 
 Table[KroneckerDelta[i, 
    j] + \[Lambda] KroneckerDelta[i, p] KroneckerDelta[q, j], {i, 1, 
   L}, {j, 1, L}]

Comment: So $\delta_{i,3}$ is the 3rd row all ones, is it not?

Comment: Yes the matrix $M$ with components $M_{i,j} = \delta_{i,3}$ has the third row full of ones.